# Upload image in collection view except for the last image in last cell of UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function in Swift which uploads pictures on to the server side, I want to modify the function so that all the images are uploaded except for the last image in the last cell in collection view. Can someone please help me on how to do this?

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: NSMutableDictionary?,boundary: String) -> NSData {

    let body=NSMutableData()

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {

            if(value is String || value is NSString){
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
            else if(value is [UIImage]){
                var i = 0
                for image in value as! [UIImage]{
                    let randomString = String.random()
                    let filename = "image_\(randomString)_\(i).jpg"
                    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);
                    let mimetype = mimeTypeForPath(filename)

                    print("In for loop the value of i is \(i)")
                    print("Filename is :\(filename)")

                    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
                    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
                    body.appendData(data!)
                    body.appendString("\r\n")
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    //        NSLog("data %@",NSString(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!);
    return body
}
```

Comment: In your `parameters`, do you only have one array of `UIImage`s or can it have several? And am I correct to assume that `parameters` is of type `[String: AnyObject]`?

Comment: Only one array of UIImages declared as "var albumImages = [UIImage]()". Parameters is of NSMutableDictionary as "var param=NSMutableDictionary() 
                
                param=[
                    "token": KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("tokenValue")!,
                    "files": self.albumImages
                ]"

Comment: And it's this `albumImages` array's last object you don't want to include in the request?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to include the last object of albumImages array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
for image in value as! [UIImage]{
    if image != (value as! [UIImage]).last {
        let randomString = String.random()
        let filename = "image_\(randomString)_\(i).jpg"
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);
        let mimetype = mimeTypeForPath(filename)

        print("In for loop the value of i is \(i)")
        print("Filename is :\(filename)")

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(data!)
        body.appendString("\r\n")
        i++
    }

}
```